# Rewriting GET variables using modrewrite, absolutely stuck

Tags: php, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting

I have a subdomain artist.DOMAIN.com, which i'm using a $_GET variable on of ?artist=ARTISTNAME

How can I modrewrite this to look like artist.DOMAIN.com/ARTISTNAME.

I'm having a real hard time with modrewrite. Haha! Also do i put the .htaccess specifically in the subdomain folder, or the root of the domain?

Comment: I think showing some effort, i.e. "what have you tried" would help you with getting some concrete answers.

Comment: Well I absolutely suck at Regex, so i've just been changing things with trial and error in the .htaccess file under the artist subdomain. I can get it working with /index/artist/section but i need to lose the index off it. The rule for that is: ^index/(\w+)/(\w+)$ /index.php?artist=$1&section=$2